# Creating a new column and assign value depeding on another column value

Tags: sql-server, view

Considering a simple view like:

```
JOB    TYPE    DAYS
 1      A       10
 2      B       2
 3      A       6
 4      C       8
```

I want to add a new column (which do not exist on the original table), called ADP. This column will be filled with values depending on the TYPE column. If that value is A, then ADP column will be filled with a `CMM` value, if its B with a `CM`, and if it's C with a `PMM` value.

The result would be like that:

```
 JOB    TYPE    DAYS    ADP
  1      A       10     CMM 
  2      B       2      CM
  3      A       6      CMM
  4      C       8      PMM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression.

```
select JOB,TYPE,DAYS,
case when TYPE = 'A' then 'CMM'
     when TYPE = 'B' then 'CM'
     when TYPE = 'C' then 'PMM'
     else null 
end as ADP
from tablename;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/21969c/2)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CASE`:

```
SELECT
  JOB,
  TYPE,
  DAYS,  
  ADP = CASE [TYPE]
         WHEN 'A' THEN 'CMM'
         WHEN 'B' THEN 'CM'
         WHEN 'C' THEN 'PMM'
         ELSE NULL
        END
FROM your_table;
```

Or you can create lookup table:

**[SqlFiddleDemo1&2](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/762df/6/1)**

```
CREATE TABLE lookup([Type] NVARCHAR(1), Val NVARCHAR(10), UNIQUE([Type]));

INSERT INTO lookup([Type], [Val])
VALUES ('A' , 'CMM'), ( 'B' ,'CM'),( 'C', 'PMM');

SELECT
  JOB,
  t.[TYPE],
  DAYS,  
  ADP = l.[val]
FROM your_table t
LEFT JOIN lookup l
  ON t.[type] = l.[type];
```

This solution may be useful if you will need this type value in many places at your system.